# Cant see server Audio Tag in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

I have

```
    <audio runat="server" id="audioMessageToPlay" src="" controls="controls"/>
```

in a user control, i want to manipulate the src tag in code behind, but when i get there the control

```
    audioMessageToPlay.src
```

isnt there ?

I cant even do

```
    audioMessageToPlay.Attributes.Add("src", "mymusic.mp3")
```

Any ideas on how to get it, im currently updating to SP1 maybe that will help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using **VS2010 SP1** and the code below works fine for me. Unfortunatelly `audioMessageToPlay.src` is not working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    audioMessageToPlay.Attributes.Add("src", "media/keineZeit.mp3");
}
```

Tried the code in **VS2008** and worked there, too. Again `audioMessageToPlay.src` is not working.
Finally checked **VS2012** - `Attributes.Add(.., ..)` **and** `src` are working!!

[image: VS2012 code behind audio tag]

*Sidenote:* **None** of my versions properly shows the *audio tag, while in designMode*.

Comment: This is great answer, but I wonder is there a way to load a byte[] as the source without having to save files on the server?

Comment: I think what you want is to play a media from a stream. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258284/stream-audio-to-a-webpage-from-c-sharp) for a possible solution